# Bootstrap - Connect 3 input types

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I hope someone can help me. At the moment it looks like that: http://www.jsfiddle.net/LhYMW/

But I want that these 3 input types (1x text, 2x password) "connect" together like the first two ones are doing it. How do I make that?

HTML:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" method="POST">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Registrieren</h2>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control test" placeholder="Username" required/>
        <input type="password"  name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort" required/>
        <input type="password"  name="password1" class="form-control" placeholder="Passwort wiederholen" required/>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="registersubmit" value="Login">Einloggen</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an additional class `.first` to your HTML

```
<input type="password"  name="password" class="form-control first" placeholder="Passwort" required/>
```

Than just add this CSS:

```
.form-signin input[type="password"].first {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

Here is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LhYMW/8/)

Comment: +1 Little better than the other answer, but I still feel like this is a hack ( since bs3 doesn't support this ). Maybe add a `z-index:` change for `:focus` and remove the shadow, and remove the bottom border :)

Answer (score 1):

You can move it up with this CSS:

```
.form-signin input[type="password"] +input[type="password"] {margin-top:-11px;}
.form-signin input:nth-child(3){border-radius: 0; }
```

...this moves a password field up 11px if it follows another password field.

see in an update to your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LhYMW/9/  (**updated** -- it needs 11px, not 10, plus removed rounding on first password)

Comment: See how the second password field is rounded at the top corners though? And the shadow from the field above goes over it. I was tinkering with this and it seems a bit more involved.

Comment: Very nice. +1. I actually prefer your way now.